# Database variable not found after upgrading PHP 5 to PHP 7

Tags: php

In the error log I'm getting the following errors:

```php
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice: Undefined variable: conn in /var/www/vhosts/mytaxe.uk/public_html/fareadmin/include/app.php on line 219
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/vhosts/mytaxe.uk/public_html/fareadmin/include/app.php on line 219
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/vhosts/mytaxe.uk/public_html/fareadmin/include/app.php on line 229
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'fare' of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/mytaxe.uk/public_html/fareadmin/include/app.php on line 232
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /var/www/vhosts/mytaxe.uk/public_html/fareadmin/include/app.php on line 234
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$miles in /var/www/vhosts/mytaxe.uk/public_html/fareadmin/include/app.php on line 239
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/vhosts/mytaxe.uk/public_html/fareadmin/include/app.php on line 191
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /var/www/vhosts/mytaxe.uk/public_html/fareadmin/include/app.php on line 193
```

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this or what has changed?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the code around line 219 in /var/www/vhosts/mytaxe.uk/public_html/fareadmin/include/app.php ?

Comment: and also add the piece of code where you show us how you create the `$conn` variable.

Comment: public function user()
{

$row = mysqli_fetch_object((mysqli_query($conn, "select * from jstadmin")));

return $row;
}                                                                                                                                                        this is the code around line 219